# How to align this implications?

Tags: alignment

I prepared my notes on algebra and I faced this :[image]

Here the first implication is not in the correct position by comparing to others, so I want to know how to align this implications ? The only problem here is the first implication. How to align this implications equally for a good look?

For this implications, I typed

```
 \begin{align*}

& a \rho b \wedge b \rho c \implies (a-b\;\text{is a multiple of $m$}) \wedge (b-c\;\text{is a multiple of $m$}) \\

 & \implies (a-b=k_1m) \wedge (b-c=k_2m) ,  k_1,k_2 \in \Bbb Z \\

 & \implies (a-b)+(b-c)=k_1m+k_2m \\

 & \implies a-c=(k_1+k_2)m \\

 & \implies a \rho c 

 end{align*}
```

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The first line of the display contains `\implies`.  To get the desired alignment, move the `&` from the beginning of the line to just before the `\implies`.  (And consider taking a look at the `amsmath` user guide -- `texdoc amsldoc`.)  Also, don't put blank lines in any math expression; that will only get you error messages.

Comment: Oh! super! its working!...Thanks! Make your comment as an answer and add other informations if any and if you wish!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you gave us no complete mwe I have to guess a little bit. Please see the following mwe

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a \rho b \wedge b \rho c 
  &\implies (a-b\;\text{is a multiple of $m$}) \wedge (b-c\;\text{is a multiple of $m$}) \\
  &\implies (a-b=k_1m) \wedge (b-c=k_2m) ,  k_1,k_2 \in \Bbb Z \\\
  &\implies (a-b)+(b-c)=k_1m+k_2m \\\
  &\implies a-c=(k_1+k_2)m \\\
  &\implies a \rho c 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Please see that I moved the first `&` in your code to `&\implies` and deleted all blank lines inside environment `align*` ...

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts!

Comment: @Chinz You are welcome!